# サーバー管理botのエラー(Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord

Discord.jsを用いてBotを作成しているものです。
このbotには、以下の機能が搭載されています。

<ロール管理>
・!login ロール名:ロール取得
・!logout ロール名:ロール剥奪

<サーバー管理>
・testロール所有者の送信テキストの代理送信
・mutedロール所有者の送信テキストの削除

コードの記述順は上の通りです。

以下はサーバー管理の部分のコードになります。

```
client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
  if (msg.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'test')) {
    msg.delete();
    msg.channel.send(`test: ${msg.content}`);
  }

//mutedロール所有者のメッセージ削除
  if (msg.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'muted')) {
    msg.delete();
  }
  
});
```

この部分の”mutedロール所有者のメッセージ削除”の部分が悪さをしているのか、mutedロールを所有しているユーザーが!logout mutedを実行しようとするとbotがエラーを起こし止まってしまいます。

内部処理としては

1. !logout mutedを検知する
2. mutedロールを持つユーザーかどうかチェックする
3. 2がtrueならメッセージ削除、falseならそのまま残す
4. 3の結果に問わずlogoutの処理が実行されるが、メッセージが削除されている場合!logout mutedの検知に失敗してエラーを起こす

となっていると思うのですが、これの対処法を教えていただきたいです。
2の処理でreturnを嚙ませるとこれまたエラーを吐いてbotが停止します。

Comment: 出ているエラーの内容を質問に追加すると、回答が得られやすくなりそうです。

Answer (score -1):

良い解答になるかよくわかりませんが、提供されているコードだけでは、正確な修正点などをお答えすることはできませんね。

やりたい機能については、スラッシュコマンドを使用した方が簡単でいいと思います。

何かあれば、言っていただければ代理でBOTの作成など行えますm(__)m